# Why do I have to specify the default port in order to connect?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

The following connection attempt works!

```
sqlcmd -S SOMEOTHERPC\SQLEXPRESS,1433 -Q "SELECT * WHERE Lol=1" -d "mydb"
```

the following does not work, it times out after 10 seconds and fails

```
sqlcmd -S SOMEOTHERPC\SQLEXPRESS -Q "SELECT * WHERE Lol=1" -d "mydb"
```

given that 1433 is the default port for sql server, why is it that I have to provide it?  used to work without it?

many applications are getting this connection time out issue And i feel it is due to this?

had the default port been changes somewhere in sqlserver config?

EDIT:

Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Windows Embedded Standard 32bit (6.1 Build 7601)

Comment: What is the express sentence brain l version. What is the win severe version?

Comment: *express sentence brain l version* say what ??? xD. Looks like google translate masterpiece

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014
Windows Embedded Standard 32bit (6.1 Build 7601)

Comment: The instance name is ignored when a port number is specified. So `-S SOMEOTHERPC\SQLEXPRESS,1433` is functionally identical to `-S SOMEOTHERPC,1433` and `-S SOMEOTHERPC`. If you specify the instance name without a port (`-S SOMEOTHERPC\SQLEXPRESS`), it should also work if the SQL Server Browser service is running and UDP port 1434 allowed through the firewall.